# Weird crash when using PIL to save screen and display by PYQT

Tags: python, pyqt, python-imaging-library

What I want to do is rather simple, grab screen intervally then show these screen images in a new window. But everytime the new window opened, the program crashed without any error message. Here's my code, environment: Win7, py 2.7, pyqt4

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PIL import ImageGrab ,Image,ImageFilter
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', parent=self)

        button.clicked.connect(self.add)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.pics = []
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.timer,QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"), self.OnTimer)
        self.timer.start( 3000 )

    def add(self):
        dialog = Dialog(self.pics,self)
        if dialog.exec_():
            self.model.appendRow((
                QtGui.QStandardItem(dialog.name()),
                QtGui.QStandardItem(str(dialog.age())),
            ))

        dialog.destroy()

    def grab(self):
        global lastCloses,checkClose
        print 'grab:'
        pic = ImageGrab.grab((480,740,1400,800)) 
        pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.CONTOUR)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.DETAIL)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        image = pic
        image.save("js.png")
        print image.size
        return image.tostring()
        imageq = ImageQt(pic) #convert PIL image to a PIL.ImageQt object
        qimage = QtGui.QImage(imageq) #cast PIL.ImageQt object to QImage object -thats the trick!!!
        return QtGui.QPixmap(qimage)
    def OnTimer(self):
        self.pics.append(self.grab())


class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,pics, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.resize(240, 200)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        for p in pics:
            l = QtGui.QLabel()
            imageq = ImageQt(Image.fromstring('RGB',(920,60),p)) #convert PIL image to a PIL.ImageQt object
            qimage = QtGui.QImage(imageq) #cast PIL.ImageQt object to QImage object -thats the trick!!!
            i = QtGui.QPixmap(qimage)
            l.setPixmap(i)
            #l.exec_()
            layout.addWidget(l)

        # ButtonBox

        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that the argument you pass to the `QImage` constructor must not be garbage collected. The documentation (see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-11)) discusses the fact that constructing a `QImage` this way uses implicit data sharing. I expect that allowing `qimage` and `imageq` to fall out of scope on the next iteration of your loop, is causing Qt to hard crash Python.

As such, I think you should modify your dialog class to

```
class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,pics, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.resize(240, 200)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.imageqs = []
        self.qimages = []
        for p in pics:
            l = QtGui.QLabel()
            imageq = ImageQt(Image.fromstring('RGB',(920,60),p)) #convert PIL image to a PIL.ImageQt object
            qimage = QtGui.QImage(imageq) #cast PIL.ImageQt object to QImage object -thats the trick!!!
            i = QtGui.QPixmap(qimage)
            self.imageqs.append(imageq)
            self.qimages.append(qimage)
            l.setPixmap(i)
            #l.exec_()
            layout.addWidget(l)

        # ButtonBox

        self.setLayout(layout)
```

This ensures you keep a references to the `QImage`s so that they are not garbage collected.

I'm also surprised you needed to explicitly cast the `ImageQt` object to a `QImage` object as well given that [this](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imageqt.htm) states `ImageQt` is a subclass of `QImage`.

Either way, you still need to retain references to `ImageQt` and `QImage` objects while they are in use (eg being used as a pixmap for a `QLabel`)

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly. As you mentioned, I tried to cast the PIL.Image Object to QImage directly, but the image could not show correctly. I guess it is necessary because Image.ImageQt() do the transform work.   You hit the nail,  now I can keep going on my small tool.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is should be error in `imageq = ImageQt(Image.fromstring('RGB',(920,60),p))` convert. Maybe convert unsuccessful. To fix it, Please avoid return string of image in `def grab(self)` and use return `image` object;

```
def grab(self):
    global lastCloses,checkClose
    print 'grab:'
    .
    .
    print image.size
    return image # Please avoid to use -> image.tostring()
```

And in class `Dialog(QtGui.QDialog)` recives string image. Change coverter from string to image object;

```
def __init__(self,pics, parent=None):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
    #self.resize(240, 200)
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    for p in pics:
        l = QtGui.QLabel()
        imageq = ImageQt(p) # Please avoid to use -> imageq = ImageQt(Image.fromstring('RGB',(920,60),p))
        .
        .
        .
```

Full code;

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PIL import ImageGrab ,Image,ImageFilter
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', parent=self)

        button.clicked.connect(self.add)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.pics = []
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.timer,QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"), self.OnTimer)
        self.timer.start( 3000 )

    def add(self):
        dialog = Dialog(self.pics,self)
        if dialog.exec_():
            self.model.appendRow((
                QtGui.QStandardItem(dialog.name()),
                QtGui.QStandardItem(str(dialog.age())),
            ))

        dialog.destroy()

    def grab(self):
        global lastCloses,checkClose
        print 'grab:'
        pic = ImageGrab.grab((480,740,1400,800)) 
        pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.CONTOUR)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.DETAIL)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
        #pic = pic.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        image = pic
        image.save("js.png")
        print image.size
        return image#.tostring()
        imageq = ImageQt(pic) #convert PIL image to a PIL.ImageQt object
        qimage = QtGui.QImage(imageq) #cast PIL.ImageQt object to QImage object -thats the trick!!!
        return QtGui.QPixmap(qimage)
    def OnTimer(self):
        self.pics.append(self.grab())


class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,pics, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.resize(240, 200)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        for p in pics:
            l = QtGui.QLabel()
            imageq = ImageQt(p) #convert PIL image to a PIL.ImageQt object
            qimage = QtGui.QImage(imageq) #cast PIL.ImageQt object to QImage object -thats the trick!!!
            i = QtGui.QPixmap(qimage)
            l.setPixmap(i)
            #l.exec_()
            layout.addWidget(l)

        # ButtonBox

        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi, I modify it as your suggestion, but it still crashes. At first I return a QPixmap in grab(), it did not work too. And all crashes happend after     layout.addWidget(l), if # this line, no crash.

Comment: That's why I try to convert image to string, I thought it may work if save all the images as files and reload them, but that's really ugly...

Comment: But, I crash in string image. I same environment Win7, py 2.7, pyqt4. OK , I put fixed code.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, but still get crashed, only a windows error tip: Python.exe crashed. So it is really wierd if it works on your machine but not on mine. @three_pineapples solved my problem, but still thanks.